# How to close BootStrap alert automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-box">
    <div class ="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> </button>             
           <?php
                foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $e) {
                    echo $e;
                }
                unset($_SESSION['error']);
           ?>   
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code that I have to print out errors using bootstrap alert, 
But however the alert box stays on the screen even when there is no errors (after refreshing the page).

I have tried to do it using `JavaScript` but it doesn't seems to work. Can someone help me to fix this problem. So that the error alert only pops up when there is an error from `$_SESSION['error]`.

Thanks

Comment: throw in an if statement to check if the session is not undefined or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways.

1) If you want to totally exclude the alert if there are no errors:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['error']) AND ! empty($_SESSION['error'])): ?>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-box">
        <div class ="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> </button>  

           <?php
                foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $e){
                                    echo $e;
                }
                unset($_SESSION['error']);
           ?>   
        </div>
</div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

2) Just hide the alert but keep it on the page. Then you could hide or show it with JS later:

```
<?php $showAlert = (isset($_SESSION['error']) AND ! empty($_SESSION['error'])) ? '' :'style="display:none;'; ?>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-box">
        <div class ="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" <?= $showAlert; ?> >
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> </button>  

           <?php
                foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $e){
                                    echo $e;
                }
                unset($_SESSION['error']);
           ?>   
        </div>
</div>
```

Just a couple options, these could be done better.

You can also hide the alert with jQuery:

```
$('.alert').hide();
```

Comment: *"GRR Why won't the code show up?"* - I edited. You had a whole bunch of `>` but unsure if you wanted to do a `2)`. It's the bullet option that messes up code indenting.

Comment: Yea, I couldn't the code to show unless a put it in a quote block. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I also don't know how some of the guys do it with bullet options.